# How to set Case Owner when a Case closes?

Tags: apex, workflow, process-builder, configuration

I'm trying to use Workflows or Process Builder to do this but maybe you'll tell me I cant.

But I work for a University and we are trying to build a way to assess Student Support Case metrics based on whom closes those cases, and to do so it looks like we need to set the Owners to be the Closers, so we know whom accomplished closing the case.

Is this doable via a declarative route, or do I need to figure out Apex?

(I tried to create a Process or Workflow that changes the Owner when Cased Closed = True, but there is no way I can find to simply set the Owner to the current $User.Id)

Thank you.

Comment: Use Process Builder....you can assign the ownerid as current user in formula...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Process builder and you can assign case whom is closing

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use Process Builder to assign current userId as Case owner during case closure as follows:

[image: Update Case Owner]